# Missing key in mapping

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-loader

Trying to upload .csv file using Aerospike loader but I keep getting this error. I am trying to figure out what I am missing.

```
ERROR Parser           :243  - "bin_list"  Key is missing in mapping. Mapping: {"set":{"column_position":1,"type":"string"},"binlist":[{"name":"number_of_requests","value":{"column_position":3,"type":"integer"}},{"name":"size_of_the_content_returned","value":{"column_position":4,"type":"integer"}}],"key":{"column_position":2,"type":"string"}}
ERROR Parser           :181  - Error in parsing mappingdef: {"set":{"column_position":1,"type":"string"},"binlist":[{"name":"number_of_requests","value":{"column_position":3,"type":"integer"}},{"name":"size_of_the_content_returned","value":{"column_position":4,"type":"integer"}}],"key":{"column_position":2,"type":"string"}}
ERROR AerospikeLoad    :213  - java.lang.Exception: Config file parsing Error
```

my config.json file looks like:

```
{ "version" : "2.0", "dsv_config": {
    "delimiter": "," ,
    "n_columns_datafile": 4,
    "header_exist": false}, "mappings": [
    {
            "key": {"column_position":2, "type": "string"},
            "set": {"column_position":1, "type": "string"},

            "binlist": [
            {"name": "number_of_requests",
            "value": {"column_position": 3, "type" : "integer"}},
            {"name": "size_of_the_content_returned",
            "value": {"column_position": 4, "type" : "integer"}}]}]}
```

Comment: @pgupta is right. it should be bin_list and not binlist. I checked the code. The doc should be fixed.

Comment: Looks like i followed an old documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wondering if "binlist" should be "bin_list". Looking in the code: public static final String BINLIST    = "bin_list";